# php : how to pass database value into a javascript/jquery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am implementing tags feature in my project.
In my demo tags i found they are passing names in a javascript function for the autocomple.

This is a function in my demo project,

```
   <script>
   $(function()
      {
          var sampleTags = ['c++', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
      ..................
      .................
```

So , i want pass values from my php controller to this function ,inorder to get the autocomplete value from my database table

```
For example i am getting tags values from my db in my Controller like this:

 ` $data["query"] = $this->ordermodel->fetch_orderlist();`
   $this->load->view('tagpage', $data);  //loading my page tag page where above function exists
```

Now how can i pass that  `$data["query"]`  values into the above javascript function?
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could echo the variable onto the page using PHP's `json_encode`. This function will convert a PHP array or object into a JSON object, which JavaScript can work with:

```
<script>
$(function() {
      var sampleTags = <?php echo json_encode($query); ?>;
})();
</script>
```

But a better way would be to request these values via Ajax. Say you have a PHP script named `values.php`:

```
<?php
    #...
    #assign $query here
    #...
    echo json_encode($query);
```

Then, in JavaScript (on the page where you want to use the `sampleTags` variable), you can use jQuery's `.ajax` function to make an easy Ajax request:

```
<script>
var sampleTags;

$.ajax({
    url: 'values.php'
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data) {
       sampleTags = data;
    }
});
</script>
```

I haven't tested this example. Obviously you'll want to tweak it to fit your environment.

Comment: I believe it would just be `$query` and not `$data['query']`

Comment: i think you mean `$data`, right? either way it's the same concept.

Comment: No I mean `$query` :) Codeigniter will separate out all the indexes of the array passed in to a view, the concept is the same yes but broken code is broken code.

Comment: @sgroves I was trying your first method for getting the list but its not working. Its not showing the list... i used this `var sampleTags = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;` in my view & my contrller & model ,those i update above in my question

Comment: @sgroves Even i tried the second way also, with ajax request. This is also not working. Now showing data...Please help...

Comment: try `json_encode($query)` or `json_encode($data[$query])`. you want to echo the PHP variable that contains the data you want in the JS variable. i'm not 100% sure what this is, as i don't have experience with codeigniter. this was just an example to show you the approach; i didn't intend for you to copy it literally into your program.

Comment: @sgroves I changed to json_encode($query), and i found in my browser after clicking on "view source"    `var sampleTags = [{"tags_name":"c++"},{"tags_name":"scala"}];`   but in to get my output it should be like this format `var sampleTags = ['c++', 'scala'];`

Comment: best place to fix that would probably be in PHP, before you echo `$query`. again, i'm not sure what the original PHP array/object looks like, but probably something like PHP's `array_values` function would work. if you can't figure it out i suggest asking a new question, as this comments section is getting rather long.

Comment: @Ashutosh looks like rikesh's comment there will help you.

Comment: @sgroves Yes that problem is solved. As you said `a better way would be to request these values via Ajax`  for this also i am tring to get but its not showing me the values   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441838/php-unable-to-get-the-json-output-into-my-javascript-page-using-ajax-request

Comment: @sgroves With ajax also i am able to get the values . Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an ajax function for this

```
$.ajax(
    url     :   "<?php echo site_url('controller/method')?>",
    type    :   'POST',
    data    :   'para=1',
    success :   function(data)
    {
        if(data){
            var sampleTags  =   data;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: well, you don't HAVE to. but ajax is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @raheel after seeing your answer , i tried your ajax function, but its not showing the output. I updated my model and  controller in my question. Please check and let me know your suggestion..

Comment: @Ashutosh i only presented you an example you can replace with your paramters. change controller and method to your controller name and method name

Comment: @raheelshan Obviously i changed those stuffs. but why its not showing the output?

Comment: @Ashutosh hit the controller method directly in browser to see if the output is coming. Also use `console.log(data)` to see if there comes anything in `data`

Comment: @raheelshan I have posted the code which i tried here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441838/php-unable-to-get-the-json-output-into-my-javascript-page-as-a-variable-value/16442261?noredirect=1#comment23582832_16442261

Answer (score 0):

Just echo your php variable

```
 $(function()
      {
          var sampleTags = '<?php echo $data["query"]; ?>'
```